# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined SweetAlert & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, sweetalert2

Was working around 5 days ago, just went onto the website and it no longer works, checked Chrome console & found this error.

Rest of the code works just fine, everything pops up as expected. the .then has just broken itself. not sure if due to an update.

Can anyone see what's going wrong? I'm new to JS, Jquery etc.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at Object.success ((index):204)
>       at c (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>       at l (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)

Here is the code that is running

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/32bd141c/dist/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/32bd141c/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
addListItem();

     }); 
function addListItem(){
        $.get("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace",     function(data) { 
            arrayOfLines = data.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
            var arrayLength = arrayOfLines.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                if(arrayOfLines[i].startsWith("loc")){
                    var countCode = arrayOfLines[i].split("=")[1]
                    var countName = getCountryName(countCode);
                    if(countCode != "US"){
                    swal({

                        title: "Looks like you're from " + countName + ". ",
                        text: "Go to our International Store? ",
                        imageUrl: 'https://www.countryflags.io/' + countCode + '/flat/64.png',
                        imageWidth: 128,
                        imageHeight: 128,
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: 'Yes take me there',
                        cancelButtonText: 'Stay on U.S.A Site',
                        imageAlt: 'Custom image',
                        dangerMode: false,
                    })
                    .then((willDelete) => {
                        if (willDelete) {
                            window.open('https://thebrainary.com/cart.php?action=buy&sku=SKU8474-82&source=HRGW','_blank');
                        }
                    });
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
var isoCountries = {
'AF' : 'Afghanistan',
'AX' : 'Aland Islands',
'AL' : 'Albania',
'DZ' : 'Algeria',
'AS' : 'American Samoa',
'AD' : 'Andorra',
'AO' : 'Angola',
'AI' : 'Anguilla',
'AQ' : 'Antarctica',
'AG' : 'Antigua And Barbuda',
'AR' : 'Argentina',
'AM' : 'Armenia',
'AW' : 'Aruba',
'AU' : 'Australia',
'AT' : 'Austria',
'AZ' : 'Azerbaijan',
'BS' : 'Bahamas',
'BH' : 'Bahrain',
'BD' : 'Bangladesh',
'BB' : 'Barbados',
'BY' : 'Belarus',
'BE' : 'Belgium',
'BZ' : 'Belize',
'BJ' : 'Benin',
'BM' : 'Bermuda',
'BT' : 'Bhutan',
'BO' : 'Bolivia',
'BA' : 'Bosnia And Herzegovina',
'BW' : 'Botswana',
'BV' : 'Bouvet Island',
'BR' : 'Brazil',
'IO' : 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
'BN' : 'Brunei Darussalam',
'BG' : 'Bulgaria',
'BF' : 'Burkina Faso',
'BI' : 'Burundi',
'KH' : 'Cambodia',
'CM' : 'Cameroon',
'CA' : 'Canada',
'CV' : 'Cape Verde',
'KY' : 'Cayman Islands',
'CF' : 'Central African Republic',
'TD' : 'Chad',
'CL' : 'Chile',
'CN' : 'China',
'CX' : 'Christmas Island',
'CC' : 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
'CO' : 'Colombia',
'KM' : 'Comoros',
'CG' : 'Congo',
'CD' : 'Congo, Democratic Republic',
'CK' : 'Cook Islands',
'CR' : 'Costa Rica',
'CI' : 'Cote D\'Ivoire',
'HR' : 'Croatia',
'CU' : 'Cuba',
'CY' : 'Cyprus',
'CZ' : 'Czech Republic',
'DK' : 'Denmark',
'DJ' : 'Djibouti',
'DM' : 'Dominica',
'DO' : 'Dominican Republic',
'EC' : 'Ecuador',
'EG' : 'Egypt',
'SV' : 'El Salvador',
'GQ' : 'Equatorial Guinea',
'ER' : 'Eritrea',
'EE' : 'Estonia',
'ET' : 'Ethiopia',
'FK' : 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
'FO' : 'Faroe Islands',
'FJ' : 'Fiji',
'FI' : 'Finland',
'FR' : 'France',
'GF' : 'French Guiana',
'PF' : 'French Polynesia',
'TF' : 'French Southern Territories',
'GA' : 'Gabon',
'GM' : 'Gambia',
'GE' : 'Georgia',
'DE' : 'Germany',
'GH' : 'Ghana',
'GI' : 'Gibraltar',
'GR' : 'Greece',
'GL' : 'Greenland',
'GD' : 'Grenada',
'GP' : 'Guadeloupe',
'GU' : 'Guam',
'GT' : 'Guatemala',
'GG' : 'Guernsey',
'GN' : 'Guinea',
'GW' : 'Guinea-Bissau',
'GY' : 'Guyana',
'HT' : 'Haiti',
'HM' : 'Heard Island & Mcdonald Islands',
'VA' : 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
'HN' : 'Honduras',
'HK' : 'Hong Kong',
'HU' : 'Hungary',
'IS' : 'Iceland',
'IN' : 'India',
'ID' : 'Indonesia',
'IR' : 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of',
'IQ' : 'Iraq',
'IE' : 'Ireland',
'IM' : 'Isle Of Man',
'IL' : 'Israel',
'IT' : 'Italy',
'JM' : 'Jamaica',
'JP' : 'Japan',
'JE' : 'Jersey',
'JO' : 'Jordan',
'KZ' : 'Kazakhstan',
'KE' : 'Kenya',
'KI' : 'Kiribati',
'KR' : 'Korea',
'KW' : 'Kuwait',
'KG' : 'Kyrgyzstan',
'LA' : 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic',
'LV' : 'Latvia',
'LB' : 'Lebanon',
'LS' : 'Lesotho',
'LR' : 'Liberia',
'LY' : 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
'LI' : 'Liechtenstein',
'LT' : 'Lithuania',
'LU' : 'Luxembourg',
'MO' : 'Macao',
'MK' : 'Macedonia',
'MG' : 'Madagascar',
'MW' : 'Malawi',
'MY' : 'Malaysia',
'MV' : 'Maldives',
'ML' : 'Mali',
'MT' : 'Malta',
'MH' : 'Marshall Islands',
'MQ' : 'Martinique',
'MR' : 'Mauritania',
'MU' : 'Mauritius',
'YT' : 'Mayotte',
'MX' : 'Mexico',
'FM' : 'Micronesia, Federated States Of',
'MD' : 'Moldova',
'MC' : 'Monaco',
'MN' : 'Mongolia',
'ME' : 'Montenegro',
'MS' : 'Montserrat',
'MA' : 'Morocco',
'MZ' : 'Mozambique',
'MM' : 'Myanmar',
'NA' : 'Namibia',
'NR' : 'Nauru',
'NP' : 'Nepal',
'NL' : 'Netherlands',
'AN' : 'Netherlands Antilles',
'NC' : 'New Caledonia',
'NZ' : 'New Zealand',
'NI' : 'Nicaragua',
'NE' : 'Niger',
'NG' : 'Nigeria',
'NU' : 'Niue',
'NF' : 'Norfolk Island',
'MP' : 'Northern Mariana Islands',
'NO' : 'Norway',
'OM' : 'Oman',
'PK' : 'Pakistan',
'PW' : 'Palau',
'PS' : 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied',
'PA' : 'Panama',
'PG' : 'Papua New Guinea',
'PY' : 'Paraguay',
'PE' : 'Peru',
'PH' : 'Philippines',
'PN' : 'Pitcairn',
'PL' : 'Poland',
'PT' : 'Portugal',
'PR' : 'Puerto Rico',
'QA' : 'Qatar',
'RE' : 'Reunion',
'RO' : 'Romania',
'RU' : 'Russian Federation',
'RW' : 'Rwanda',
'BL' : 'Saint Barthelemy',
'SH' : 'Saint Helena',
'KN' : 'Saint Kitts And Nevis',
'LC' : 'Saint Lucia',
'MF' : 'Saint Martin',
'PM' : 'Saint Pierre And Miquelon',
'VC' : 'Saint Vincent And Grenadines',
'WS' : 'Samoa',
'SM' : 'San Marino',
'ST' : 'Sao Tome And Principe',
'SA' : 'Saudi Arabia',
'SN' : 'Senegal',
'RS' : 'Serbia',
'SC' : 'Seychelles',
'SL' : 'Sierra Leone',
'SG' : 'Singapore',
'SK' : 'Slovakia',
'SI' : 'Slovenia',
'SB' : 'Solomon Islands',
'SO' : 'Somalia',
'ZA' : 'South Africa',
'GS' : 'South Georgia And Sandwich Isl.',
'ES' : 'Spain',
'LK' : 'Sri Lanka',
'SD' : 'Sudan',
'SR' : 'Suriname',
'SJ' : 'Svalbard And Jan Mayen',
'SZ' : 'Swaziland',
'SE' : 'Sweden',
'CH' : 'Switzerland',
'SY' : 'Syrian Arab Republic',
'TW' : 'Taiwan',
'TJ' : 'Tajikistan',
'TZ' : 'Tanzania',
'TH' : 'Thailand',
'TL' : 'Timor-Leste',
'TG' : 'Togo',
'TK' : 'Tokelau',
'TO' : 'Tonga',
'TT' : 'Trinidad And Tobago',
'TN' : 'Tunisia',
'TR' : 'Turkey',
'TM' : 'Turkmenistan',
'TC' : 'Turks And Caicos Islands',
'TV' : 'Tuvalu',
'UG' : 'Uganda',
'UA' : 'Ukraine',
'AE' : 'United Arab Emirates',
'GB' : 'United Kingdom',
'US' : 'United States',
'UM' : 'United States Outlying Islands',
'UY' : 'Uruguay',
'UZ' : 'Uzbekistan',
'VU' : 'Vanuatu',
'VE' : 'Venezuela',
'VN' : 'Viet Nam',
'VG' : 'Virgin Islands, British',
'VI' : 'Virgin Islands, U.S.',
'WF' : 'Wallis And Futuna',
'EH' : 'Western Sahara',
'YE' : 'Yemen',
'ZM' : 'Zambia',
'ZW' : 'Zimbabwe'
};

function getCountryName (countryCode) {
    if (isoCountries.hasOwnProperty(countryCode)) {
        return isoCountries[countryCode];
    } else {
        return countryCode;
    }
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you are using `swal` version `v1.0.0`.

Use below syntax instead of `swal({}).then()`.

```
swal({
  title: "Looks like you're from " + countName + ". ",
  text: "Go to our International Store? ",
  imageUrl: 'https://www.countryflags.io/' + countCode + '/flat/64.png',
  imageWidth: 128,
  imageHeight: 128,
  showCancelButton: true,
  showConfirmButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes take me there',
  cancelButtonText: 'Stay on U.S.A Site',
  imageAlt: 'Custom image',
  dangerMode: false,
}, function () {
  // Your code
});
```

[Reference Link](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/87)

OR

replace your `cdn` link of `sweetalert` with latest version - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/sweetalert.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    addListItem();

});
function addListItem() {
    $.get("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", function (data) {
        arrayOfLines = data.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
        var arrayLength = arrayOfLines.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            if (arrayOfLines[i].startsWith("loc")) {
                var countCode = arrayOfLines[i].split("=")[1];
                var countName = getCountryName(countCode);
                
                if (countCode != "US") {
                  swal({
                    title: "Looks like you're from " + countName + ". ",
                    text: "Go to our International Store? ",
                    imageUrl: 'https://www.countryflags.io/' + countCode + '/flat/64.png',
                    imageWidth: 128,
                    imageHeight: 128,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes take me there',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Stay on U.S.A Site',
                    imageAlt: 'Custom image',
                    dangerMode: false,
                  }).then(function() {

                  });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
var isoCountries = {
    'AF': 'Afghanistan',
    'AX': 'Aland Islands',
    'AL': 'Albania',
    'DZ': 'Algeria',
    'AS': 'American Samoa',
    'AD': 'Andorra',
    'AO': 'Angola',
    'AI': 'Anguilla',
    'AQ': 'Antarctica',
    'AG': 'Antigua And Barbuda',
    'AR': 'Argentina',
    'AM': 'Armenia',
    'AW': 'Aruba',
    'AU': 'Australia',
    'AT': 'Austria',
    'AZ': 'Azerbaijan',
    'BS': 'Bahamas',
    'BH': 'Bahrain',
    'BD': 'Bangladesh',
    'BB': 'Barbados',
    'BY': 'Belarus',
    'BE': 'Belgium',
    'BZ': 'Belize',
    'BJ': 'Benin',
    'BM': 'Bermuda',
    'BT': 'Bhutan',
    'BO': 'Bolivia',
    'BA': 'Bosnia And Herzegovina',
    'BW': 'Botswana',
    'BV': 'Bouvet Island',
    'BR': 'Brazil',
    'IO': 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
    'BN': 'Brunei Darussalam',
    'BG': 'Bulgaria',
    'BF': 'Burkina Faso',
    'BI': 'Burundi',
    'KH': 'Cambodia',
    'CM': 'Cameroon',
    'CA': 'Canada',
    'CV': 'Cape Verde',
    'KY': 'Cayman Islands',
    'CF': 'Central African Republic',
    'TD': 'Chad',
    'CL': 'Chile',
    'CN': 'China',
    'CX': 'Christmas Island',
    'CC': 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
    'CO': 'Colombia',
    'KM': 'Comoros',
    'CG': 'Congo',
    'CD': 'Congo, Democratic Republic',
    'CK': 'Cook Islands',
    'CR': 'Costa Rica',
    'CI': 'Cote D\'Ivoire',
    'HR': 'Croatia',
    'CU': 'Cuba',
    'CY': 'Cyprus',
    'CZ': 'Czech Republic',
    'DK': 'Denmark',
    'DJ': 'Djibouti',
    'DM': 'Dominica',
    'DO': 'Dominican Republic',
    'EC': 'Ecuador',
    'EG': 'Egypt',
    'SV': 'El Salvador',
    'GQ': 'Equatorial Guinea',
    'ER': 'Eritrea',
    'EE': 'Estonia',
    'ET': 'Ethiopia',
    'FK': 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
    'FO': 'Faroe Islands',
    'FJ': 'Fiji',
    'FI': 'Finland',
    'FR': 'France',
    'GF': 'French Guiana',
    'PF': 'French Polynesia',
    'TF': 'French Southern Territories',
    'GA': 'Gabon',
    'GM': 'Gambia',
    'GE': 'Georgia',
    'DE': 'Germany',
    'GH': 'Ghana',
    'GI': 'Gibraltar',
    'GR': 'Greece',
    'GL': 'Greenland',
    'GD': 'Grenada',
    'GP': 'Guadeloupe',
    'GU': 'Guam',
    'GT': 'Guatemala',
    'GG': 'Guernsey',
    'GN': 'Guinea',
    'GW': 'Guinea-Bissau',
    'GY': 'Guyana',
    'HT': 'Haiti',
    'HM': 'Heard Island & Mcdonald Islands',
    'VA': 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
    'HN': 'Honduras',
    'HK': 'Hong Kong',
    'HU': 'Hungary',
    'IS': 'Iceland',
    'IN': 'India',
    'ID': 'Indonesia',
    'IR': 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of',
    'IQ': 'Iraq',
    'IE': 'Ireland',
    'IM': 'Isle Of Man',
    'IL': 'Israel',
    'IT': 'Italy',
    'JM': 'Jamaica',
    'JP': 'Japan',
    'JE': 'Jersey',
    'JO': 'Jordan',
    'KZ': 'Kazakhstan',
    'KE': 'Kenya',
    'KI': 'Kiribati',
    'KR': 'Korea',
    'KW': 'Kuwait',
    'KG': 'Kyrgyzstan',
    'LA': 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic',
    'LV': 'Latvia',
    'LB': 'Lebanon',
    'LS': 'Lesotho',
    'LR': 'Liberia',
    'LY': 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
    'LI': 'Liechtenstein',
    'LT': 'Lithuania',
    'LU': 'Luxembourg',
    'MO': 'Macao',
    'MK': 'Macedonia',
    'MG': 'Madagascar',
    'MW': 'Malawi',
    'MY': 'Malaysia',
    'MV': 'Maldives',
    'ML': 'Mali',
    'MT': 'Malta',
    'MH': 'Marshall Islands',
    'MQ': 'Martinique',
    'MR': 'Mauritania',
    'MU': 'Mauritius',
    'YT': 'Mayotte',
    'MX': 'Mexico',
    'FM': 'Micronesia, Federated States Of',
    'MD': 'Moldova',
    'MC': 'Monaco',
    'MN': 'Mongolia',
    'ME': 'Montenegro',
    'MS': 'Montserrat',
    'MA': 'Morocco',
    'MZ': 'Mozambique',
    'MM': 'Myanmar',
    'NA': 'Namibia',
    'NR': 'Nauru',
    'NP': 'Nepal',
    'NL': 'Netherlands',
    'AN': 'Netherlands Antilles',
    'NC': 'New Caledonia',
    'NZ': 'New Zealand',
    'NI': 'Nicaragua',
    'NE': 'Niger',
    'NG': 'Nigeria',
    'NU': 'Niue',
    'NF': 'Norfolk Island',
    'MP': 'Northern Mariana Islands',
    'NO': 'Norway',
    'OM': 'Oman',
    'PK': 'Pakistan',
    'PW': 'Palau',
    'PS': 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied',
    'PA': 'Panama',
    'PG': 'Papua New Guinea',
    'PY': 'Paraguay',
    'PE': 'Peru',
    'PH': 'Philippines',
    'PN': 'Pitcairn',
    'PL': 'Poland',
    'PT': 'Portugal',
    'PR': 'Puerto Rico',
    'QA': 'Qatar',
    'RE': 'Reunion',
    'RO': 'Romania',
    'RU': 'Russian Federation',
    'RW': 'Rwanda',
    'BL': 'Saint Barthelemy',
    'SH': 'Saint Helena',
    'KN': 'Saint Kitts And Nevis',
    'LC': 'Saint Lucia',
    'MF': 'Saint Martin',
    'PM': 'Saint Pierre And Miquelon',
    'VC': 'Saint Vincent And Grenadines',
    'WS': 'Samoa',
    'SM': 'San Marino',
    'ST': 'Sao Tome And Principe',
    'SA': 'Saudi Arabia',
    'SN': 'Senegal',
    'RS': 'Serbia',
    'SC': 'Seychelles',
    'SL': 'Sierra Leone',
    'SG': 'Singapore',
    'SK': 'Slovakia',
    'SI': 'Slovenia',
    'SB': 'Solomon Islands',
    'SO': 'Somalia',
    'ZA': 'South Africa',
    'GS': 'South Georgia And Sandwich Isl.',
    'ES': 'Spain',
    'LK': 'Sri Lanka',
    'SD': 'Sudan',
    'SR': 'Suriname',
    'SJ': 'Svalbard And Jan Mayen',
    'SZ': 'Swaziland',
    'SE': 'Sweden',
    'CH': 'Switzerland',
    'SY': 'Syrian Arab Republic',
    'TW': 'Taiwan',
    'TJ': 'Tajikistan',
    'TZ': 'Tanzania',
    'TH': 'Thailand',
    'TL': 'Timor-Leste',
    'TG': 'Togo',
    'TK': 'Tokelau',
    'TO': 'Tonga',
    'TT': 'Trinidad And Tobago',
    'TN': 'Tunisia',
    'TR': 'Turkey',
    'TM': 'Turkmenistan',
    'TC': 'Turks And Caicos Islands',
    'TV': 'Tuvalu',
    'UG': 'Uganda',
    'UA': 'Ukraine',
    'AE': 'United Arab Emirates',
    'GB': 'United Kingdom',
    'US': 'United States',
    'UM': 'United States Outlying Islands',
    'UY': 'Uruguay',
    'UZ': 'Uzbekistan',
    'VU': 'Vanuatu',
    'VE': 'Venezuela',
    'VN': 'Viet Nam',
    'VG': 'Virgin Islands, British',
    'VI': 'Virgin Islands, U.S.',
    'WF': 'Wallis And Futuna',
    'EH': 'Western Sahara',
    'YE': 'Yemen',
    'ZM': 'Zambia',
    'ZW': 'Zimbabwe'
};

function getCountryName(countryCode) {
    if (isoCountries.hasOwnProperty(countryCode)) {
        return isoCountries[countryCode];
    } else {
        return countryCode;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are amazing, updating my link to sweetalert fixed it, I tried using the function method you posted. but for some reason, it was saying there were extra brackets.
I checked and they seemed like they should all be there. But you have solved my problem. now I just need to update the deprecated changes. Thanks again